# PHP explode() to several variable where

Tags: php, explode

My exact situation is a bit long to explain and possibly irrelevant.

I know I can do this:

```
list($id, $type, $data, $directive) = explode("*", $data);
```

my data will be like `1234*A*bf233d2d*F`

where id is `1234`, of type A and data is in HEX `bf,23,3d,2d` ...I later use split string to get each data...no worries there either...BUT the last one `F` is directive to mean its the first data ( or something else )..which MAY or may not be present...so in case its not present there will (obviously) be an indexing error..

Any workaround to this??

Comment: Frame the question nicely else it will be closed soon, time starts now

Comment: `list($id, $type, $data, $directive) = explode("*", $data . '*');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @MarkBaker +1 for simplest solutions

Comment: I'd use a regex for this...

Comment: Well..How about that!!! 
That does solve my problem...But since we're here maybe we could look for a solution which will give more freedom...

Something clean like isset() function ???

Comment: @KushalKafle read http://stackoverflow.com/help . You need to open anothe question for it. Or edit current question.

Comment: @KushalKafle If you want to use isset, then you have already answered your question. First check and save the directive, unset it from original array, then do a list ofthe remaining three values. This is just as elegant as any other solution using explode.

Comment: @MaximKumpan: How can I check for the directive first?? and the $data is not in array but in string..So I cannot retrieve 'only' the directive section..(without using regex that is). So there is no way to use isset() for that...Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarkBaker: Can you post that as an answer please, your solution is better for my purpose than regex.

Comment: @KushalKafle You are missing the fact that `explode('*', $data)` evaluates to an array that you can process any way you like.

Comment: @MaximKumpan : Ohh !! Sorry for Being dumb :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a regex.

```
preg_match('/\A(\d+)\*(\w)\*(\w+)\*?(F?)\Z/', $data, $matches);

$id = $matches[1];
$type = $matches[2];
$data = $matches[3];
$first = $matches[4];
```

You can use [this tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to fine-tune your regex.